# How to export custom types through an interface and then to a children in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

What I am trying to do is to first, use a defined custom type (in its options interface) in a class definition.
Currently, I get a "Cannot find name 'colorsType' on my Parent's private `colors` attribute definition.

Then I'd like to know how can I pass this `colorsType` custom type to a children object. Is this possible or do I need to redefine the custom type everytime I want to use it? Here's an exemple of my code structure:

The Parent Object such as

```
export class Parent {
    private colors: colorsType[] = [];
    private property2: string;

    constructor(options: ParentOptions) {
    this.colors = options.colors;
    this.property2 = options.property2;
  }
}
```

Having a defined interface:

```
export interface ParentOptions {
    colors: colorsType[];
    property2: string;
}
export type colorsType =
| "blue"
| "yellow"
| "red"
| "black";

export default ParentOptions
```

Then his children:

```
export class Children extends Parent {
    private property3: number;

    constructor(options: SomeOtherOptions)
        super(options);
        this.property3 = options.property3;
}
```

So that I can instanciate a children object as:

```
let object = new Children({
    colors: ["blue", "yellow"], //being of colorsType[]
    property2: "foo",
    property3: 42
});
```

Comment: Update ** For now I took out in another file the colorsType definition in order to import it everywhere I need. It does works, but I was still wondering if it was possible to do it another way so that I don't have to import it in every children files.

Comment: If you can, then just use an intersection conjoining the `ParentOptions` with the new options for the `Children` class. Otherwise, see my answer using the `ConstructorParameters` built-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the type of the parameters from a constructor of a class using the `ConstructorParameters` type then providing the class definition. Using that, you can form a intersection to join the object from the `Parent` constructor parameter with a `{ property3: number }` to allow for the extra property in the `Child` class.

```
export interface ParentOptions {
  colors: colorsType[];
  property2: string;
}
export type colorsType =
  | "blue"
  | "yellow"
  | "red"
  | "black";

export class Parent {
  private colors: colorsType[] = [];
  private property2: string;

  constructor(options: ParentOptions) {
    this.colors = options.colors;
    this.property2 = options.property2;
  }
}

export class Children extends Parent {
  private property3: number;

  constructor(options: ConstructorParameters<typeof Parent>[0] & { property3: number }) {
    super(options);
    this.property3 = options.property3;
  }
}

let object = new Children({
    colors: ["blue", "yellow"],
    property2: "foo",
    property3: 42
});
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgBUymBQHkwYEIkBnOAbwFgAoOObCAG2hoC52uPACoBPMMADaAXQDcLNmCgRxsEQCZ+NGFGQBzOcwC+LUJFhwYYvB25Qao8XAC88uAB84AIgBGnAK7Anq4eniLAnNwA7kGs7l7EACYxbCG+OADWngYm4NDw2JyYNHSExCgMrooIAG6YqAK2fA3CVtLOcNIGCjq19YrKaJYacFo6SPosrhy02n7YMNAAFMqU1E2lJDDkq7QAlBWxbDAAFgg0AHQ2PO0rVLSXgnZdbBanF-0qQzcUd+9Kn+pnsYjJNmKY8uxCsU4ABhU6cBJlOCgVBIBIlIibA7dGp1PAfQYiADM-CQfgAtt40NlYtNRnMFlBlj81vwYWtZvNoKVMOTgKg7AAeSziCDoAiYlAAPgkAAYpHAAGQMOAE1QkuBkyloOCGfZMQ4jPwqZk7Gi7Z5HN7nNWWInfM02-6EolAljAlicflwCDeABWwHm7SQwEisPhiJIiwNL2adn4Eh8-kCABovGEIhBolI0wB6XNUvQ+8VXOwOSRSVzdAaqYaedAQCCeFNV1XO9X8AAsandFqAA)